# Angular6: How can I generate a default angular.json file from command line

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli-v6

I create a new module using angular 6, that will serve as a package to use in another project.

Now, I'm trying to configure the karma and jasmine so I could create unit tests on it. The problem is that I found out that the project does not have any `angular.json` file.

It is possible to generate a default `angular.json` file from the command line?

Comment: ng new project then copy and paste it in to your real project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to do as danday74 suggested and generate a new project and copy the angular.json file from that generated project:

```
ng new project-name
```

A quick inspection of the "ng" command line options doesn't reveal any options for generating a new angular.json independently:

```
 ng -h
```

> ```
> Available Commands:
>   add Add support for a library to your project.
>   new Creates a new directory and a new Angular app.
>   generate Generates and/or modifies files based on a schematic.
>   update Updates your application and its dependencies.
>   build Builds your app and places it into the output path (dist/ by default).
>   serve Builds and serves your app, rebuilding on file changes.
>   test Run unit tests in existing project.
>   e2e Run e2e tests in existing project.
>   lint Lints code in existing project.
>   xi18n Extracts i18n messages from source code.
>   run Runs Architect targets.
>   eject Temporarily disabled. Ejects your app and output the proper webpack configuration and scripts.
>   config Get/set configuration values.
>   help Help.
>   version Outputs Angular CLI version.
>   doc Opens the official Angular API documentation for a given keyword.
> ```

You could also manually create your own angular.json based on the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace) provided by the [Angular CLI project on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).